# Karabiner like features with xmodmap

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

Karabiner for OS X has a few features that I would like to get in Fedora.

- You can hold `Tab` and use `h` and `l` to switch between the running apps (Tab basically works as a modifier)
- You can hold `s` and use `hjkl` keys as arrow-keys (`s` works as a modifier - tapping on `s` shortly - emits the letter)

Is this possible with xmodmap or maybe other apps in Linux?

Comment: Not with xmodmap. Making a key work both as a modifier and directly is not possible with X11, you'd have to route the key to an application and make it figure out whether it's used as a modifier or not and generate fake keyboard events when it isn't used a modifier.

Comment: Does  that not mean that a `s` cannot be inserted until you release the `s` key and that you can't input a sequence of `s` by holding the `s` key?

Comment: I have found that certain keyboard customization possible using `xbindkeys` and `xte` or `xdotools`, but I'm on Fedora 26, now it seems in Wayland they introduced some security restrictions and neither `xte` or `xdotools` really work there ;(. Dammit! I need to find a workaround.

Comment: You might try https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools